# Trying to do a natural join using python standard library

Tags: python, sql, csv

I have 4 tables:

1. `shops` (attributes: `shop_id`, `name`, `lat`, `lng`)
2. `products` (attributes: `product_id`, `shop_id`, `title`, `popularity`
3. `tags` (attributes: `tag_id`, `tag`)
4. `taggings` (attributes: `tagging_id`, `shop_id`, `tag_id`)

I want to do a natural join over all my tables to produce one table only. A natural join is the same as an inner join except `shops.shop_id` = `products.shop_id` = `taggings.shop_id` and `tags.tag_id` = `taggings.tag_id`.

```
import csv

print "This is going to take a while ..."    

shops = list(csv.reader(open('data/shops.csv'), delimiter=','))
products = list(csv.reader(open('data/products.csv'), delimiter=','))
tag = list(csv.reader(open('data/tags.csv'), delimiter=','))
taggings = list(csv.reader(open('data/taggings.csv'), delimiter=','))


shops_products = []

hash_ = {}
for idx, row1 in enumerate(shops):
    hash_[row1[0]] = idx 

for row2 in products:
    if row2[1] in hash_:
        shops_products.append(shops[hash_[row2[1]]] + row2)


print "shops_products done ..."
print len(shops_products)


tags_taggings = []

hash_ = {}
for idx, row1 in enumerate(tag):
    hash_[row1[0]] = idx 

for row2 in taggings:
    if row2[2] in hash_:
        tags_taggings.append(tag[hash_[row2[2]]] + row2)


print "tags_taggings done ..."
print len(tags_taggings)
```

Now I have 2 tables named `shops_products`, `tags_taggings`. If I merge them together, I get the table that I want.

However, `shops_products` and `tags_taggings` has many rows with the same `shops_id` so I cannot merge them the way I merged the tables `shops`, `products`, `tags`, `taggings`.

I could merge them using a nested loop, but that would result in O(n^2) complexity, over 40 minutes to complete.

I need help figuring out how to do this the way I joined my other tables as in the code. That would be a satisfactory O(n) and finish fairly quickly.

Comment: Could you show a sample of what the final table would look like?

Comment: it is going to have attributes shop_id,name,lat,lng  product_id,shop_id,title,popularity,quantity  tag_id,tag_name,tagging_id,shop_id,tag_id



I know some attributes have the same name, this is just a side effect of merging the tables without going to the trouble of figuring out how to remove the duplicate columns for now, but the duplicate attributes will have the same information. If you need any other information that is going to help you get a better picture let me know please and thanks

Comment: Would the `products` table have more than one reference to the shop? e.g. There are two products with the same `shop_id`.

Comment: Yes @MoonCheesez the `products` table will have products that have the same `shop_id` .  `taggings` table will also have many rows that have the same `shop_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer was ...

```
from collections import defaultdict
s_p_t_t=[]
hash_= defaultdict(list)
for idx, row in enumerate(shops_products):
    hash_[row[0]].append(idx)

for row in tags_taggings:
    if row[3] in hash_:
        for x in hash_[row[3]]:
            s_p_t_t.append(shops_products[x]+row)
```